# Rails app Load Error, Couldn't start the app with 'rais s' command, instead I'm getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

My rails local development was just fine, but suddenly the every thing is broken after trying RubyMine, I was just using sublime text as editor  for my projects and then wanted to tryout RubyMine.

Now at this stage I can't start any application with 'rails s' command.
I tried install new app with 'rails new myapp' but the problem still exists.

I am new for rails and I am stuck, any help would be appreciated!! Thanks!

here is the error I  am getting

```
hemps-MBP:experiment hemp$ rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
    58: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    57: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    56: from /Users/hemp/Documents/tutorials/ROR/experiment/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    55: from /Users/hemp/Documents/tutorials/ROR/experiment/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    54: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    53: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    52: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    51: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    50: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    49: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    48: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    47: from /Users/hemp/Documents/tutorials/ROR/experiment/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    46: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    45: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    44: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    43: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    42: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    41: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    40: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    39: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    38: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    37: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    36: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    35: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    34: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    33: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    32: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    31: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    30: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
    29: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
    28: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
    27: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
    26: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    25: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    24: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    23: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    22: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    21: from /Users/hemp/Documents/tutorials/ROR/experiment/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    20: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    19: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    18: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    17: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    16: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    15: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bundler-1.16.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    14: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    13: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    11: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    10: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
     9: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<main>'
     8: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <main>'
     7: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
     6: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
     5: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
     4: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
     3: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
     1: from /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': dlopen(/Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _rb_cFixnum (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle - /Users/hemp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle
hemps-MBP:experiment hemp$
```

Comment: You are deploying against ruby 2.5.1, and you probably developed against a lower version. Anyways: the version of sqlite you are trying to deploy seems to be not compatible with ruby 2.5.1 as it is missing the `_rb_cFixnum` symbol? Which version of ruby and rails did you develop in?

Comment: Can you try `spring stop` in the terminal? Sometimes it can have very cryptic or misleading errors after certain changes to the application.

Comment: in sublime its running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue with Gemfile. Please remove the gem sqlite3 and try once. If it's not resolved then try to use diff ruby version using RVM.